# Is there a workaround for adding too much data to a header file?

Tags: c, header-files

I'm currently making a game with "multiple choices" which means a lot of questions. My thoughts first are making each question in a single .h file and then call the content inside the main file.

This means that I will have to include hundreds of header files. I don't know if this is okay as I'm new to programming. Is there any solution to this?

Here is an example on one of my headers.

```
void questionOne() {

**Code here**

}
```

Comment: You can put the questions and answers in a text file, that is not part of the C compilation. In any case, they should not be in a `.h` header file, which is for declarations, type definitions, macros etc. (but not data or executable code).

Comment: Yes, I do put them in a text file. But then, I will be making hundreds of functions to read the txt content. Plus, it is multiple choices, so every answer leads to different questions and I'm still not sure on how to put all different questions and answers in one text file. Unless again, I make hundreds of text files. @WeatherVane

Comment: You should only have **one** function to ask **any** of the questions, whether the questions are external data or hard coded. If you have one function per question and later decide to change the presentation style (or fix a bug) you have a tremendous amount of work to update everything. That would be very inflexible. However you proceed, don't prepare more than three question/choices/answer sets, until you have the code working the way you want it. That means, if you do set out with one function per question to get you going, it will be easier to convert it the next incarnation.

Comment: Example text file (one question + choices + answer per line): first question `"What is the capital of the Free World?", "Shangri-La", "Xanadu", "El Dorado", "Brigadoon", 3` or similar. Or, if you want hard coded data, use one array of `struct` containing initilaised data.